# Store AUTO_INCREMENT column in other table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table **CLIENT** with `client_id` as auto increment.
Now i need to populate other tables **SERVICE, COSTUMERS** and **STOCK** at same time.
Problem is that i need to enter the newly generated `client_id` from CLIENT in other tables too.

Right now what i am doing:

1. I insert a row in CLIENT table.
2. Fetch MAX(client_id) from that table.
3. Put it into others.

**Here i am worried about consistency as it all depends on guess that MAX(client_id) would be recently generated one. Is there any other way to do so without putting consistency at risk ??**

Help Please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may achieve it using

```
mysql_insert_id()
```

It will return the AUTO INCREMENT value in the last query. If last query doesn't generate an auto-increment value, it will return 0.

For further information, consider to take a look at [Php.net manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

**EDIT:**

As you mentioned, Mysql is deprecated and to use Mysqli or PDO will be more secure.

[**Mysqli**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)

Procedural style: `mysqli_insert_id ( mysqli $link )`

Object oriented style: `$mysqli->insert_id`

[**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

`$PDO->lastInsertId()`